# What is the right way of conditionally declaring a macro in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm working with the following project structure

```
Project
|
| -Lib
|  -lib.vcxproj
|  -lib.h
|  -lib.cpp
| -UnitTest
|  -unittest.vcxproj
|  -driver.cpp
|  -constants.h
```

Now my constants.h looks like below

```
#ifndef UNITTESTS_MACROS_H
#define UNITTESTS_MACROS_H

#ifdef UNITTESTS
#define MY_TEST_MACRO 1
#else
#define MY_TEST_MACRO 0
#endif

#endif // UNITTESTS_MACROS_H
```

I have defined the `UnitTests` constant in the `unittest.vcxproj` file. Using following code

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>
 %(PreprocessorDefinitions);
  UNITTESTS
</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

I'm including `constants.h` in `driver.cpp` and `lib.h`. I want the macro `MY_TEST_MACRO` to be initialized to `1` when I'm compiling the UnitTest. But despite giving the preprocessor macro in `unittest.vcxproj`, the macro `MY_TEST_MACRO` is not initialized to `1` while accessing through `lib.h`. I'm including reference to `constants.h` in `lib.vcxproj` through the following
`<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>`tag.
How do I initialize `MY_TEST_MACRO` to `1` while building `UnitTest` and keep it `0` while building `Lib` on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Those are separate projects, so value should be changed for both of them at same time. Rather you should do that via configurations, by utilizing output of test-enabled configuration of `Lib` in `unittest` project.

Comment: Any idea how to configure vcxproj of lib to accomplish that? Thanks.